# show output from script that would be seen in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, output

I have working scripts for windscribe vpn. At this time there is no GUI. They run from the desktop no problem. How do I see the output that I would see in the terminal.

I can get the notification window up but how do I get the output in there?

I don't think it matters what the commands are there must be basic command to make this happen.

Is there a better way than using notification window?

Comment: If you want to see the output anyhow, but neither run the commands in the terminal or [have it saved in a logfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133887/show-output-from-script-that-would-be-seen-in-terminal#comment1879440_1133895), how *do* you intend to get the output? Do you want the command to open up a new terminal window and print the output to it so that you can close that when you reviewed the output?

Comment: Maybe that is exactly what I want. See connected or disconnected or see report of account status then be on my way. How do I open terminal in script to see I guess is what I am asking.

Comment: This is confusing - you have no GUI, yet you run these scripts from a desktop? A desktop implies you have a GUI... Do you have `zenity` that can display info windows?

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the output to some files, e.g. like this:

```
./yourscript.sh 1> log.txt 2> errlog.txt
```

then you could open another terminal window and there you could do something like

```
tail -f log.txt
```

and then you should see the output there. The -f option to the tail command means that output is appended as the file grows.

Comment: Well, I don't need to keep a log. Anyway if i run script in terminal, I can see what is happening.

Comment: @StaggerLee The whole point is not in keeping the log but in the fact that stdin stream of a script or any other command is tied to controlling terminal. No terminal -  no output stream. But of you tie stdin to file, you can view it in any terminal

Answer (score 1):

Despite the Q saying you don't have a GUI, apparently you have a Desktop and gnome-terminal, so I'm assuming you also have zenity installed too (it's in Ubuntu by default), so you could have zenity display the output from a command, or from an entire script, like this:

```
script_output=$(script.sh)
zenity --info --title="Output of script" --text="$script_output"
```

It will save the standard output (excluding stderr, you could redirect it to stdout too if you wanted) to a variable, then have zenity open a window showing the output in a box similar to this image (but with a different title & contents) that will stay up until you press ok.

[image]

Comment: OP explicitly askes “Is there a better way than using notification window?”, but then again the whole question is not really clear – your answer is definitely a good solution and helpful. +1

Comment: That's another contradiction in the Q, asking "I can get the notification window up but how do I get the output in there?" and also asking for a better way than a notification window... I don't know how they would see anything at all without using a terminal or some type of window notifying them... and they don't seem to be answering with any updates. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new terminal window and run the command in it, e.g. with [`xterm` [image: Install xterm]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xterm):

```
xterm -hold -e 'whoami'
```

The `-hold` option lets the window stay open, remove it if you want it to auto-close immediately when the process exits. You can also use `sleep` to let it stay open for a defined period of time after the exit, e.g. `xterm -e 'whoami;sleep 2'. The part after`-e` is the command or command list to be executed in the new terminal window. This must be the last option on the command line. Note that it doesn’t run a shell if you don’t tell it to do so.

Most other terminal emulators have the same or a similar option, e.g.

```
gnome-terminal -e 'whoami'
```

If there’s no equivalent to `xterm`’s `-hold` flag you can start a shell to keep the window open:

```
xterm -e 'whoami;bash'
```

Comment: Thank you dessert, xterm does not work for me, gnome-terminal does.          My next question - Does anyone know what to use to make pause or sleep or waite other than using global setting in terminal to keep open.   because I cant really see whats going on.

Comment: your information is good but i'm new to linux I had no clue about installing xterm terminal now i do, problem solved this line works perfect for me, xterm -e "command to run; sleep 3" I am still searching what to do in gnome terminal just because.